# Disable scrolling when navigating with arrows up and down

Tags: vue.js, sass, navigation, scrollbar, arrow-keys

I have a serach bar where users can filter a list of products and navigate through this list using arrows up and down.The filtering and navigation work ok, but there is a side effect of using the arrows that I haven't been able to surpress: using them makes all the page scroll (if it's large enough to have a scrollbar), and if the page hasn't got the scrollbar, the list won't scroll properly either (as shown on second and third images).

My search bar looks like this:

[image: The expanded search bar list]

In the two images below you can see that when using arrow down first, the element is partially hidden; and when using the arrow up first (the list starts being navigated bottom to top, then the element is hidden entirelly from the screen.

[image: Here you can see the first time I navigate with arrow down, the list goes up making the content disapear a little]

[image: Here, I am navigating starting from the bottom, and the content is out of the view]

My `.vue` file looks like this:

```
<template>
  <form class="ui-search-bar" role="search" aria-label="Produtos à venda">
    <input
      aria-label="Pesquisar por produto"
      class="ui-input"
      @focus="enableArrowNavigation"
      placeholder="Pesquisar"
      type="text"
      v-model="search"
      @keydown.up="navigateUp"
      @keydown.down="navigateDown"
    />
    <div class="ui-search-bar__wrapper">
      <div>
        <ul v-if="copied_parents.length > 0">
          <li class="ui-search-bar__grandpa" :key="i" v-for="(parent, i) in copied_parents">
            <p>{{ parent.title }}</p>
            <ul class="ui-search-bar__parent" :key="j" v-for="(child, j) in parent[children_key]">
              <li
                class="ui-search-bar__children"
                :data-category="child.title"
                :key="k"
                v-for="(grandchild, k) in child[grandchildren_key]"
              >
                <a
                  :href="grandchild.route"
                  @keydown.up="navigateUp"
                  @keydown.down="navigateDown"
                  tabindex="-1"
                  v-if="grandchild.quantity > 0"
                >
                  {{ grandchild.title }}
                </a>
                <p v-else>
                  {{ grandchild.title }} -
                  <span> Esgotado </span>
                </p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <p v-else-if="parents.length <= 0">Não há produtos disponíveis para compra.</p>
        <p v-else>Não há resultados para esta pesquisa.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["children_key", "grandchildren_key", "parents"],
  data() {
    return {
      amount_of_children: 0,
      copied_parents: this.makeParentCopy(),
      search: "",
      selected_child: 0,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    search(value) {
      if (value.length >= 3) {
        this.copied_parents = this.filterItems(value);
      } else {
        this.copied_parents = this.makeParentCopy();
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.amount_of_children = document.querySelectorAll(".ui-search-bar__children a").length;
  },
  methods: {
    makeParentCopy() {
      return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.parents));
    },
    filterItems(needle) {
      this.copied_parents = this.makeParentCopy();

      const filtered_items = this.copied_parents.filter((parent) => {
        const children = parent[this.children_key].filter((child) => {
          const grandchildren = child[this.grandchildren_key].filter((product) => {
            return product.title.toLowerCase().includes(needle.toLowerCase());
          });
          child[this.grandchildren_key] = grandchildren;
          if (grandchildren.length > 0) {
            return child;
          }
        });
        parent[this.children_key] = children;
        if (children.length > 0) {
          return children;
        }
      });

      return filtered_items;
    },
    enableArrowNavigation() {
      this.selected_child = 0;
    },
    navigate() {
      document.querySelectorAll(".ui-search-bar__children a")[this.selected_child - 1]?.focus();
    },
    navigateDown() {
      if (this.selected_child === this.amount_of_children) {
        this.selected_child = 1;
      } else {
        this.selected_child++;
      }
      this.navigate();
    },
    navigateUp() {
      if (this.selected_child > 1) {
        this.selected_child--;
      } else if (this.selected_child === 1) {
        this.selected_child = this.amount_of_children;
      }
      this.navigate();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And the `.sass` looks like this:

```
@use "../abstracts/colours" as c;
@use "../abstracts/shorthands" as s;
@use "../abstracts/media" as m;

.ui-search-bar {
  padding: 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  z-index: 100;
  & input {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 110;
  }
  &:focus-within > .ui-search-bar__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  &__children {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    & a,
    & p {
      border-radius: 6px;
      color: c.$darker-gray;
      display: inline-block;
      @include s.font(14);
      padding: 1px 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 100%;
    }
    & p {
      color: c.$dark-gray;
      & > span {
        color: c.$red;
        @include s.font(16);
        font-variant-caps: all-petite-caps;
      }
    }
    a:focus,
    a:hover {
      @include m.desktop-up {
        background-color: c.$gray;
        outline-color: c.$gray;
        outline-style: solid;
        outline-width: 2px;
      }
    }
    &:first-of-type::before {
      color: c.$dark-gray;
      content: attr(data-category);
      @include s.font(14);
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
  &__grandpa {
    & > p {
      color: c.$lead;
      @include s.font(18);
    }
    &:not(:first-of-type) {
      margin-top: 15px;
    }
    &:last-of-type() {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
  }
  &__parent {
    border-top: 1px solid c.$gray;
    padding: 5px 0;
  }
  &__wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px -5px #1d283a;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    max-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    & > div {
      overflow-y: auto;
      padding-inline: 10px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    & > div > ul {
      width: 100%;
    }
    & > div > p {
      color: c.$dark-gray;
      @include s.font(18, 500);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't really found anything that could help me with this. I guess it's because I don't really know if this is a `css` or `js` problem, and that's why I come to you: maybe someone will have a hint what could be causing this and hopefully a solution too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default browser behavior by calling `event.preventDefault()`.

In Vue.js you can do this directly in the template like so:

```
<input
    ...
    @keydown.up.prevent="navigateUp"
    @keydown.down.prevent="navigateDown"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had actually tried this before, but instead of using `prevent` after the `up` or `down`, I used it before.

Comment: Yes, order of the modifiers matter because the code is generated in that order, you can read more about it in the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers).